# Should direct speech be used in synopses?

Tags: grammar, indirect-speech

When you're writing a synopsis for a book, a movie, or a show, is it acceptable to use direct speech? Does it look professional? Or is it better to use indirect speech when it can convey the meaning just as well?

Comment: This would probably be better asked in [writing.se]